# Get id of event target in vanilla javascript

Tags: javascript

This is probably a dumb question but how do I get the `id` of the `event.target` in vanilla javascript(not jQuery!).

I know that this can be used to get the classList:

```
event.target.classList.contains('class')
```

But is there a way to get the `id` instead.

Thanks.

Comment: `event.target.id`?

Comment: ookay..Thank you.